# regex to parse a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a simple regex in java, and for some reasons my regx is not working.

What I want to achieve is to parse a string that is,

- Starts with number 9
- Has exactly 10 digit (including prefix 9)

My Regex is `(^9\\d[0-9]{10})` and I want to parse as an example, 91234567890. But it is not working.

Comment: The string "not working" is not a built-in error message in Java.

Comment: @JackManet It sounds like he means the regex isn't matching, not that there's an Exception persay

Comment: @AlexColeman: <nitpick>`per se` is Latin and means "by itself" or "in itself".</nitpick>

Comment: @TimPietzcker I'm taking latin, but didn't know that, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have escaped the `[` (because that made your regex expect a literal `[` after the `9`).

Also, 1 + 10 = 11, so you need to lower the quantifier.

Finally, use the end-of-string anchor `$` to make sure that no other characters occur after the 10th digit:

```
^9[0-9]{9}$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
9[0-9]{9}
```

should work. It looks for the number 9, followed by 9 more numbers

Comment: @TimPietzcker good point, though I assumed he would be using it to match more than one instance